# Google Analytics GA4

Tags: django, database, google-analytics, analytics, web-testing

The number of users who have registered on my website on GA4 is less than the one I got from the DB.
Anyone can help here?

Both google analytics and extracted data are in the UTC time and on GA4 Im checking the total users value

Thannk you!

Answer (score 0):

The totals are probably lower due to thresholding. In GA4, metrics displayed are often just an estimate or less than expected.